# How to send pop up message from an app in django to account app in the same django project

Tags: python, django, modal-dialog, popupwindow

I have a django project file. The project contains 2 apps, first app is Account App for staffs or users and the second app is Web-Visitor App. When the Web-Visitor visitor the website, they get to fill a form that contains their details and email or username of one of the staffs/users. Then they submit the form. When they click submit button,a pop up comes up on the web-visitor device showing ("Please wait for response from user") and another pop up comes up on the user's device (if online). The pop up on the user's device shows 3 buttons. The user clicks one of the buttons on the pop up, when the user clicks the button, a message is sent to the web-visitor's pop up, showing some String as message like "The user(name) accept ur request.

After this, the details is recorded in database.

Comment: Hello, is your issue making the two apps interact on the back end, or transmitting a signal to the front end ?

Comment: Hi Divine, welcome to SO! Please read up on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next one. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes. Two apps interacting on the back end and displaying results on the front end

Comment: Am so sorry Diggy. This is my first question. I will read the link sent. Thanks a lot